# Loading rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem. from Resource Folder in AWS lambda java

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

Am trying to load "rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem"  to connect DocumentDB   from AWS Lambda it is getting  the file when run test lambda from eclipse because the file is at root of the directory.But when upload the jar to AWS console as Lamdba Function  file is at resource floder and test it. Getting NULL pointer Exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.adp.hyperx.documentdb.LambdaFunctionHandler.createCertificate(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:156)
at com.adp.hyperx.documentdb.LambdaFunctionHandler.createKeyStoreFile(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:144)
at com.adp.hyperx.documentdb.LambdaFunctionHandler.setSslProperties(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:131)
at com.adp.hyperx.documentdb.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:64)
at com.adp.hyperx.documentdb.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:46)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:178)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:293)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)




private static X509Certificate createCertificate() throws Exception 
     {
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    // System.out.println(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem"));
     Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.class.getResource("/").toURI());
    System.out.println("path" + path);
    Path resourceLocation = path.resolve("rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem");
    System.out.println("resourceLocation" + resourceLocation);
     URL url = resourceLocation.toFile().toURI().toURL();
    // URL url = new File(SSL_CERTIFICATE).toURI().toURL(); --this one reads the file from root floder
     if (url == null) {
        throw new Exception();
      }
      try (InputStream certInputStream = url.openStream()) {
        // FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        return (X509Certificate) 
     certFactory.generateCertificate(certInputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

  }
```

I have  used the same code as  RDS but for Document DB https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html for  IAMDatabaseAuthenticationTester class

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i store the file in the resource folder, and the below works:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
```

Comment: can you please share the sample code for this. I'm getting timeout repeatedly